# Trouble combining multiple objects in the same mesh

Tags: sculpting

just having a little trouble combining the 4 bodies in the attached image so I can continue to sculpt. They show up as being a part of the same mesh,[image] but will not blend together in sculpt mode. Thanks for your help!

-MC

Comment: You will have to separate them and combine them with a boolean (unnion) modifier.

Comment: Ok, great. What command can I use to separate them?

Comment: [Link to the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/misc.html?highlight=separate%20vertices#separate)

Answer (score 1):

**Blender 2.8 edits all selected objects**

> *"They show up as being a part of the same mesh,"*

A new feature of blender 2.8 is the ability to edit more than one object at once.  When entering edit mode, all selected mesh objects toggle into edit mode.

Going by the outliner in screenshot this is the case.

There is no need to separate them again.  Separating adds the newly separated object in object mode, so it appears to work, but is probably unnecessary

To edit one at a time, toggle out of edit mode, select only one object and toggle back in.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! P in edit mode to separate by selection. Thanks Leander!